# Why couldnt we have moving iterators?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

C++11 introduced a "move" algorithm that behaves like the "copy" algorithm except that it... moves the data instead of copying it. I'm wondering why the commitee didnt update the copy algorithm to use forward instead (or probably in addition to that).

A vector provides an iterator of T&
A const vector provides an iterator of const T&
Is there a reason why a vector&& couldnt provide an iterator of T&&? That would allow to move elements from say a list to a vector by using vector's constructor...

Is that a bad idea?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We have those already. Use [`std::make_move_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/make_move_iterator) to create a move iterator.

Comment: @sasha.sochka (maybe just remove those comments if they're no longer useful?)

Answer (score 10):

See `std::move_iterator`.

```
#include <list>
#include <vector>

#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    A() = default;
    A(A&&) {std::cout << "move\n";}
    A(const A&) = default;
};

int main()
{
    std::list<A> l = {A(), A(), A()};
    std::vector<A> v(std::make_move_iterator(l.begin()),
                     std::make_move_iterator(l.end()));
}

move
move
move
```